# From C ++ to Haskell Classes and States

Tags: c++, haskell, monads

I have to transform this C++ code

```
class A {

public: 
   int x_A;

    void setX_A (int newx) {
        x_A = newx;
    }

    void printX_A() {
       printf("x_A is %d", x_A);
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    int x_B;

    void setX_B (int newx) {
       x_B = newx;
    }

    void printX_B() {
       printf("x_B is %d", x_B);
    }

};

main() {
    A objA;
    B objB;
    objA.setX_A(2);
    objA.printX_A();
    objB.printX_A();
    objB.setX_B(5);
    objB.printX_B();
}
```

into Haskell code, and simulate `main()` using State (or StateT) Monad.

What I have done so far is this:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Identity

-- Fields For A
data FieldsA = FieldsA {x_A::Int} deriving (Show)

    -- A Class Constructor
constA :: Int -> FieldsA
constA = FieldsA

class A a where
    getX_A :: StateT a IO Int
    setX_A :: Int -> StateT a IO ()
    printX_A :: StateT a IO ()

instance A FieldsA where
    getX_A = get >>= return . x_A
    setX_A newx = do
        fa <- get
        put (fa { x_A = newx })
    printX_A = do
        fa <- get
        liftIO $ print fa
        return ()


data FieldsB = FieldsB{ fa::FieldsA, x_B::Int } deriving (Show)

constB :: Int -> Int -> FieldsB
constB int1 int2 = FieldsB {fa = constA int1, x_B = int2}

class A b => B b where
    getX_B :: StateT b IO Int
    setX_B :: Int -> StateT b IO ()
    printX_B :: StateT b IO ()

-- A Functions for Class B
instance A FieldsB where
    getX_A = do
      (FieldsB (FieldsA x_A) x_B) <- get
      return (x_A)
    setX_A newx = do
        (FieldsB (FieldsA x_A) x_B) <- get
        put (constB newx x_B)
    printX_A = do
        fb <- get
        liftIO $ print fb
        return ()
-- B specific Functions
instance B FieldsB where
    getX_B = get >>= return . x_B
    setX_B newx = do
        fb <- get
        put (fb { x_B = newx })
    printX_B = do
        fb <- get
        liftIO $ print fb
        return ()

test :: StateT FieldsA (StateT FieldsB IO ) ()
test = do
      x <- get
      setX_A 4
      printX_A

      --lift $ setX_A 99
      --lift $ setX_B 99
      --lift $ printX_A
      --lift $ printX_B

      --printX_A
      return ()

go = evalStateT (evalStateT test (constA 1)) (constB 2 3)
--go = runIdentity $ evalStateT (evalStateT test (constA 1)) (constA 1)
```

test being `main()`.

Now about the problem I have: When I use lift, it works ok, because the function becomes of type `StateT` `FieldsB`, but when I try to use `setX_A` without lift there is a problem

```
*** Type           : StateT FieldsA IO ()
*** Does not match : StateT FieldsA (StateT FieldsB IO) ()
```

If I change the type of `setX_A` to the second one, then It won't work when I use it with lift (because class B is derived from A).

Comment: What you are trying to do is very non-functional.  Are you sure you really need to do this?  You can certainly translate what you have to Haskell, but I can almost guarantee that it's the wrong thing to do.  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Added homework tag on a hunch, based on the wording and the nature of the problem.  Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @luqui Nope, you're right :P. @augustss I know it's very non-functional, but that's what I have to do. I just need help with that last step.

Comment: Have you heard of the `MonadState` type-class?  It may be of help here.

Comment: @luqui I'm new to functional programming, and I find these Monads very hard to understand, so it would help me very much if you can give an example starting from the code I have written. (Like... instead of *** use ***, or, this snippet *** does the matching). Thank you :D

Comment: @epicrose Just avoid state transformers and put all your operations in IO.  Then you can make you instance variable an IORef and you can update it in the method.  BTW, this looks like really stupid homework.  I don't understand the purpose of it.

Comment: @augustss, I disagree. Translating programs between languages really helps understanding both of those languages and helps one to relate new concepts to the known ones. Also, putting everything into the IO monad defeats the purpose of this exercise, making it trivial.

Comment: Also, no Haskell can objectively be called non-functional unless it uses some of the purity-subverting features (like `unsafePerformIO`)

Comment: @Rotsor Putting everything in the IO monad is the most true translation of the C++, because there you are always in the IO monad.  Also, I don't subscribe to the view that just because you're avoiding `unsafePerformIO` it's functional.  Functional in spirit is much more than that.

Comment: With enough effort you can, as they say, write FORTRAN in any language. Haskell is no exception.

Comment: @augustss: You know, I just remembered, but you're clearly [a highly-qualified expert](http://augustss.blogspot.com/2009/02/regression-they-say-that-as-you-get.html) on the subject of writing non-functional code in Haskell. :) Seems rather appropriate for this question, actually...

Comment: @camccann I never claimed I couldn't translate the code to Haskell.  I was just questioning the sanity of it.  It's as insane as writing BASIC in Haskell.

Comment: @augustss: Yes, I know. :) At least the BASIC has the benefit of some dubious nostalgia. Now I'm wondering about doing one for LOGO...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your problem is that you don't have a nice way to specify which object you are operating on. To solve the matter I propose using a separate program state, enclosing both of the objects:

```
data MainState = MainState { objA :: FieldsA, objB :: FieldsB }
```

Now your main function monad can look like this:

```
type Main t = StateT MainState IO t
```

And, to select the object you are working with you can use something like this:

```
withObjA :: StateT FieldsA IO t -> Main t
withObjB :: StateT FieldsB IO t -> Main t
```

The usage will be like the following:

```
test :: Main ()
test = do
    withObjA $ do
        setX_A 2
        printX_A
    withObjB $ do
        printX_A
        setX_B 5
        printX_B
```

**Update:**

Here is how one can implement `withObjA` and `withObjB`:

```
withPart :: Monad m => (whole -> part) -> (part -> whole -> whole) -> StateT part m t -> StateT whole m t
withPart getPart setPart action = do
    whole <- get
    (t, newPart) <- lift $ runStateT action (getPart whole)
    put (setPart newPart whole)
    return t

withObjA :: StateT FieldsA IO t -> Main t
withObjA = withPart objA (\objA mainState -> mainState { objA = objA })

withObjB :: StateT FieldsB IO t -> Main t
withObjB = withPart objB (\objB mainState -> mainState { objB = objB })
```

Here, function `withPart` promotes `action` operating on a `part` to an action operating on a `whole`, using `getPart` to extract part from a whole and `setPart` to update part of the whole. I'd be grateful if someone told me of a library function doing something similar. `withObjA` and `withObjB` are implemented by passing their respective accessor functions to `withPart`.

Comment: I like it very much the way you describe it. thank you very much. I thought of this but I didn't know how can I access small portions of a MainState. Still, the interpreter it says `Missing binding for variable "withObjA" in type signature`. How should I implement withObjA ? :-s. thanks again.

Comment: @epicrose Those can be implemented in terms of `get`, `put` and `runStateT`, or maybe somewhat nicer. I will update my answer later today to show it.

Comment: D Thanks, that was the part I was looking all along.

Answer (score 13):

First of all, thank you for the amount of detail given, it makes it much easier to understand your problem!

Now, the approach you're taking here is probably not ideal. It introduces a new `StateT` for each object, which is what's causing a lot of the difficulties you're experiencing, and adding more objects will make things progressively worse. Also complicating matters is that Haskell doesn't have a built-in notion of *subtyping*, and imitating it with type class contexts will... work, sort of, it's clumsy and not the best.

While I'm sure you realize this is very imperative-style code and translating it to Haskell directly is a bit silly, that's the assignment, so let's talk about ways to do this that are a bit closer to standard Haskell.

### Imperative code

#### State Monad Style:

Setting `IO` aside for now, to do something like this in pure code the typical approach would be something like:

- Create a data type holding all your state
- "Modify" the state with `get` and `put`

For output, you can use `StateT` around `IO`, or you could add a field to the state data representing the output, holding a list of `String`s, and do the whole thing without `IO`.

This is closest to the "right" way to do your current approach, and is roughly what @Rotsor suggests.

#### IO Monad Style

The above still requires that all mutable variables be specified beforehand, outside the function, by defining them in the state data. Rather than juggle things this way, you could also imitate the original code more directly and use real, honest-to-god mutable state in `IO`. Using just `A` as an example, you'd have something like this:

```
data FieldsA = FieldsA { x_A :: IORef Int}

constA :: Int -> IO FieldsA
constA x = do xRef <- newIORef x
              return $ FieldsA xRef

class A a where
    getX_A :: a -> IO Int
    setX_A :: a -> Int -> IO ()
    printX_A :: a -> IO ()

instance A FieldsA where
    getX_A = readIORef . x_A
    setX_A = writeIORef . x_A
    printX_A a = getX_A a >>= print
```

This is conceptually much closer to the original, and is along the lines of what @augustss suggested in the comments on the question.

A slight variation is to keep the object as a simple value, but use an `IORef` to hold the current version. The difference between the two approaches is roughly equivalent to, in an OOP language, a mutable object with setter methods that change internal state vs. immutable objects with mutable references to them.

### Objects

The other half of the difficulty is in modeling inheritance in Haskell. The approach you're using is the most obvious one that many people jump to, but it's somewhat limited. For instance, you can't truly use objects in any context where a supertype is expected; e.g., if a function has a type like `(A a) => a -> a -> Bool`, there's no simple way to apply it to two different subtypes of `A`. You'd have to implement your own casting to the supertype.

Here's a sketch of an alternate translation that I would argue is both more natural to use in Haskell, and more accurate to OOP style.

First, observe how all the class methods take the object as a first argument. This represents the implicit "this" or "self" in OOP languages. We can save a step by pre-applying the methods to the object's data, to get a collection of methods already "bound" to that object. We can then store those methods as a data type:

```
data A = A { _getX_A :: IO Int
           , _setX_A :: Int -> IO ()
           , _printX_A :: IO ()
           }

data B = B { _parent_B :: A 
           , _getX_B :: IO Int
           , _setX_B :: Int -> IO ()
           , _printX_B :: IO ()
           }
```

Instead of using type classes to provide methods, we'll use them to provide *casting to a supertype*:

```
class CastA a where castA :: a -> A
class CastB b where castB :: b -> B

instance CastA A where castA = id
instance CastA B where castA = _parent_B
instance CastB B where castB = id
```

There are more advanced tricks we could use to avoid making a type class for each pseudo-OOP "class", but I'm keeping things simple here.

Notice that I prefixed the object fields above with underscores. That's because those are specific to the type; now we can define the "real" methods for any type that can be cast to the one we need:

```
getX_A x = _getX_A $ castA x
setX_A x = _setX_A $ castA x
printX_A x = _printX_A $ castA x

getX_B x = _getX_B $ castB x 
setX_B x = _setX_B $ castB x
printX_B x = _printX_B $ castB x
```

To construct new objects, we'll use functions that initialize the internal data--equivalent to private members in an OOP language--and create the type representing the object:

```
newA x = do xRef <- newIORef x
            return $ A { _getX_A = readIORef xRef
                       , _setX_A = writeIORef xRef
                       , _printX_A = readIORef xRef >>= print
                       }

newB xA xB = do xRef <- newIORef xB
                parent <- newA xA
                return $ B { _parent_B = parent
                           , _getX_B = readIORef xRef
                           , _setX_B = writeIORef xRef
                           , _printX_B = readIORef xRef >>= print
                           }
```

Note that `newB` calls `newA` and gets the data type holding its member functions. It can't access the "private" members of `A` directly, but it could replace any of `A`'s functions if it wanted to.

Now we can use these in a way that's almost identical, both in style and meaning, to your original, e.g.:

```
test :: IO ()
test = do a <- newA 1
          b <- newB 2 3
          printX_A a
          printX_A b
          setX_A a 4
          printX_A a
          printX_B b
```

Comment: @camccann That's another interesting implementation, though it doesn't use the State Monad. Thank you for your detailed response :D.

Comment: @epicrose: Yes, I used the `IO` style for the second part because it's more accurate to the intent of the original code, which I wanted to emphasize. The considerations are largely orthogonal, however, and my approach to modeling the objects could be easily combined with the `State`-based approach to modeling mutability that @Rotsor demonstrates. Also, keep in mind that both are pretty terrible and you'd never want to write Haskell this way in practice. Then again, you wouldn't want to write C++ like the original, either.

Comment: It should be noted that `(A a) => a -> a -> Bool` can be changed to `(A a1, A a2) => a1 -> a2 -> Bool` to avoid the said problem, or said why this isn't possible.

Comment: @Rotsor: That avoids the problem only in simple cases, unfortunately. I probably should have chosen a better example. How about a higher-order "combine sorted lists" function that takes a comparison function, two sorted lists of items, and returns the merged and sorted list?

Comment: @Rotsor: The funny part is that the rules for how types can be substituted for each other is actually something many OOP languages get wrong, so to some extent Haskell's lack of built-in subtyping doesn't really make things any worse! Though it's not as bad these days as it used to be.